# Missing firebase token

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication

i'm developing a flutter app with firebase and i have problem with the login with google on android the same code work without any problem with ios. In android i recive a missing token error and can't login. I try to chance the code read documentation and other tread but can't sole nothing.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

abstract class AuthBase {
  User? get currentUser;
  Stream<User?> authStateChanges();
  Future<User?> signInWithGoogle();
  Future<User?> signInAnonymously();
  Future<void> signOut();
}

class Auth implements AuthBase {
  final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Stream<User?> authStateChanges() => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges();

  @override
  User? get currentUser => _firebaseAuth.currentUser;

  @override
  Future<User?> signInAnonymously() async {
    final userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();
    return userCredential.user;
  }

  @override
  Future<User?> signInWithGoogle() async {
    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();

      if (googleUser != null) {
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

        if (googleAuth.accessToken != null && googleAuth.idToken != null) {
          final UserCredential authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(
            GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
              accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
              idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
            ),
          );
          return authResult.user;
        } else {
          throw StateError('Missing Google Auth Token');
        }
      } else {
        throw StateError('Google Sign-In aborted');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error signing in with Google: $e");
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    await googleSignIn.signOut();
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```

I see i'm not the first with this issue but i don't find a solution, someone have any idea how to solve it?

I just like to have android version work well like ios

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your application using flutter fire or manually for both android and IOS? It seems like your application didn't find the Firebase config that is needed for authentication.

[Flutter fire](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android)